# Python iteration through files name in range 001-100

Tags: python, file, iteration

I have a problem. I need to iterate through files in directory with the following structure - **filename[number1]-[number2].png** .Number 1 is in range 01-10 and number 2 is in range 000-200. Examples of files names are **file02-132.png** or **file09-099.png** .Thanks for any help.

i know how to iterate for example

fnames = ['file{}.png'.format(i) for i in range(1,200)]

for fname in fnames:

#do stuff

But it doesn't work with files like this for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a fixed width with leading zeros in the format specifier:

```
fnames = ['file{:03}.png'.format(i) for i in range(1, 200)]
```

See the [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) section in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

here my attempt:

```
fnames = ['file{:02}-{:03}.png'.format(ii, i)  for ii in range(0,10) for i in range(1, 200)]

for i in fnames:
    print(i)
```